# Foreground service getting killed within ~10 mins after device locked

Tags: android, service, location, foreground-service

I am running a `foreground service` with `START_STICKY` mode in my app. Service is actively fetching location and send to server. Following is the service declaration in `Manifest`. I have tested this in android 9 onwards on different devices, but most of them have same behaviour.

```
 <service
        android:name="com.xyz.util.LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Service works well till device is in unlocked state but when device is locked, `service get auto killed by OS with in 10 mins` inspite of starting it in `START_STICKY` mode.

How can i make it ensure that service should remain running until we explicitly call `stopService()` method in app.

Comment: Just making sure you are taking into account [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: @MorrisonChang How can i restart my service again by checking periodically if serveice is running ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is Power Saving mode of your device.
In some cases almost on xiaomi devices you have to check power saving mode that can restrict your service.
One the other things that i think may solve your problem is starting your notification on your service.
If your notification kill your service have been killed after some seconds.
Please check these two items and if correct all things please update your question with your service content and starting notification code.